# How to I re-activate "history" on firefox?T

Tags: firefox

The "history" dropdown has quit working, as have "File", "Edit", and the rest at the top of the firefox toolbar.  How do I get these restarted?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

This Mozilla Support page may help you. By refreshing Firefox, it will store all settings, personal data, add-ons etc. in a new profile folder. You will not lose anything you've modified to your liking.

On another note, I'd suggest you start using Google Chrome ;-)
Hope this helped.

/edit_2/